# FFT for Arbitrary time history

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, transform, fast-convolution

I have two Time-Speed histories one is real ( real measurements) the other is synthetically generated using formula. I need to compare both in the frequency domain using FFT given that:

1. the time step at which the measurements taken is not uniform (0,540,6060,1200,...etc.) it depend on the availability of the data.
2. the maximum time in seconds is 73440.
3. total number of measurements are 64 (2^6) ?
4. The comparison in the time domain revealed very good correlation.

How can I do this, since the FFT require equidistance time step ?
and what is the frequency step on the X axis will be ?

Comment: You can use a fixed length buffer to store the incoming data and then perform the FFT.

Comment: To help clarify, what is your goal of comparing in the frequency domain? Separate comment: in case you may be interested in measuring similarity of two time series, you may also consider Granger test (cf. this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172226/proving-similarities-of-two-time-series))

Comment: exactly, I am interested to proof similarity of two time series in both time domain and frequency domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different breeds of [NUDFT : Non-uniform discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_discrete_Fourier_transform). In your case, the adjoint NDFT or nonuniform discrete Fourier transform of type II (NUDFT-II) may be useful: a uniform  frequency grid $f_k = k$ for both signals, each with a  nonuniform sample point grid $p_n$.
Lomb-Scargle periodograms are another solution; Matlab has a native  [`plomb``](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/plomb.html) function.

Beware, 64 samples is relatively low, and edge/periodic effects may happen, so it can be wise to preprocess the data (centering, detrending, tappering) before interpreting spectra.

Comment: Can I implement NUDFT-II in matlab ?

Comment: For sure. First, you can already try with [`plomb``](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/plomb.html), a native Matlab function